# How can I load translations from files using TranslateHttpLoader and still add more translation data dynamically?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

My application has static JSON files for most translations, but some user-generated data also has translations and I'd like to load that translation data on-demand.

I'm currently using TranslateHttpLoader to load the JSON files, but it causes translations loaded by `setTranslation()` to be ignored.

Is there a way to load static files and also be able to load additional data on-demand?